# Chamar Activity pelo WebView

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro aplicativo `Android`, utilizando **java** e estou tendo dificuldades para chamar uma `Activity` através do `Webview`.

Na Activity que aparece primeiro, contém apenas um Webview que carregará um php contendo o *login* do sistema.

Estou tentando fazer com que ao clicar no botão login, que está no *php*, será verificado se o login é valido e se for, após a verificação que o usuário existe, ele chame a próxima Activity.

Ao procurar no Google, me aparece que eu teria que criar um `JavascriptInterface`. Eu já tentei fazer essa interface mas o comando startActivity parece ser pulado.
Em outro lugar, eu encontrei um usuário falando que deve ser usado startActivityForResult, pois é assíncrono, mas eu não consegui implementar.

Abaixo estão os códigos que estou utilizando:

**ActivityInicial:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicial);
        webViewObj2 = findViewById(R.id.webViewInicial);
        webViewObj2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()) ;
        webViewObj2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewObj2.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webViewObj2.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webViewObj2.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "novaActivity");
        webViewObj2.loadUrl("http://localhost/Arquivar/index.php");
    }

@JavascriptInterface
    public void abrirOutraActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //durante o debug, chega até essa linha
        startActivity(intent); //mas não executa essa

    }
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
    <section>
                <div>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['nao_autenticado'])):
                    ?>
                    <div>
                      <p>ERRO: Usuário ou senha inválidos.</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endif;
                    unset($_SESSION['nao_autenticado']);
                    ?>
                    <div>
                        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                              <input name="usuario" name="text" placeholder="Seu usuário" autofocus="">
                              <input name="senha" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha">
                              <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "query de busca do usuário";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>
    novaActivity.abrirOutraActivity(); //o método se encontra no ActivityInicial.java
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Patrimônio"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityInicial">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
            android:parentActivityName=".ActivityInicial"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>
```

**Main2Activity:** (A Activity que deveria ser aberta)

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBarCabecalho);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha fazer isso com a Webview é uma péssima maneira, WebView consome recursos absurdo além de não ser nada indicada pra acessar seu service. A maneira correta é fazer uma requisição pra seu script PHP, assim você pode conferir o resultado e comparar se o usuario é autenticado ou não. 
Muito simples de fazer usando a blibioteca  [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) da Google.